# Google Drive: Files were converted to Google Document type. How can I convert them back to their original type?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Some JPG files that are stored in my Google Drive account were converted to Google Documents (.gdoc). How can I convert them back to JPG? The same happened to some HTML files.

I can see them online but would like to convert their type in order to be able to open them using an Image Viewer.

Comment: Google Drive is a storage. That might have something to do with it. You can save a document to google drive; store it there. But to store a Google Doc in Google Drive is asking software to do something it's not handled to do I think. Google Docs for "documents" made in Google Doc. Google Drive for saving files that you've created on your PC, like a .txt file or a .doc file, or something you downloaded and storing them there.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My goal is to simply convert those .gdoc files to their original type (JPG). I would like to know how I can do it.

Comment: Looks like you are in luck: Here is the reverse instructions. But if you do the revers it will reverse your situation. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/bqMt1tsqpR8 But possibly if you've done that by accident, it might be irreversible on the website itself and you'd have to find a softare.

Comment: Thanks  but unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: It's never happened to me, but I remember my mom sent me pictures in a Word file. Weird I know. But I was able to get those images out of the "wrapper". Maybe if you think of it as a wrapper? Maybe you can download it from your own drive and save-as another format? I'm just trouble shooting aloud. But maybe that can help you figure it out.

Comment: DOC to JPG: https://convertio.co/doc-jpg/
Drive Converter: https://www.driveconverter.com/

Comment: http://www.openthefile.net/extension/gdoc
Is it my understanding that a .gdoc is just a wrapper, a storage extension but not the actual document itself. I think .gdoc is just a reference, not an actual DOC as you might think. So in that reasoning all files are gDoc's on Google Drive, but really they are exactly what you uploaded them as. I think if you download the file it will still be a JPEG. Let me know what the file becomes when you DOWNLOAD your file back to your desktop computer.

Comment: Thank you: this was solved. When I download .gdoc files via Google Drive web interface (selecting folders or files, then right click and select download), I get .docx files inside a zip file. Your comment made me realise that it is possible to convert from .docx to jpg. I successfully used http://www.zamzar.com/convert/docx-to-jpg and https://convertio.co/docx-jpg/  to convert them. Please, write this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's never happened to me, but I remember my mom sent me pictures in a Word file. Weird I know. But I was able to get those images out of the "wrapper". Maybe if you think of it as a wrapper? Maybe you can download it from your own drive and save-as another format? I'm just trouble shooting aloud. But maybe that can help you figure it out.

**Wrapper:** openthefile.net/extension/gdoc

Is it my understanding that a .gdoc is just a wrapper, a storage extension but not the actual document itself. I think **.gdoc** is just a **reference**, not an actual DOC as you might think. So in that reasoning all files are gDoc's on Google Drive, but really they are exactly what you uploaded them as. I think if you download the file it will still be a JPEG. Let me know what the file becomes when you DOWNLOAD your file back to your desktop computer.

**OP Solved own problem as a result using reasoning:**

1. zamzar.com/convert/docx-to-jpg and
2. convertio.co/docx-jpg to convert them